# TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElementNS' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-started-with-d3-and-react-c7da74a5bd9f/) to put a bar chart made with d3 in my React app, but I'm getting an error when I try to call `const svgCanvas = d3.select(this.canvas).append("svg")` which makes me think that my `this.canvas` ref is set up wrong.

When I put

```
console.log(this.canvas);
console.log(d3.select(this.canvas));
```

before the commands that throw the error, these are the outputs:

```
{current: div}
  current: null
  __proto__: Object
```

```
R {_groups: Array(1), _parents: Array(1)}
  _groups: Array(1)
    0: Array(1)
      0:
        current: null
        __proto__: Object
      length: 1
      __proto__: Array(0)
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
  _parents: Array(1)
    0: null
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
  __proto__: Object
```

The following is the BarChart component that gets called from another file.

```
import React from 'react';

import * as d3 from 'd3';

class BarChart extends React.Component {
  public canvas: any;

  public constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.canvas = React.createRef();
  }

  public componentDidMount() {
    const data = [2, 4, 2, 6, 8];
    this.drawBarChart(data);
  }

  public drawBarChart(data: number[]) {
    const canvasHeight = 400;
    const canvasWidth = 600;
    const scale = 20;
    const help = d3.select(this.canvas);
    const svgCanvas = d3.select(this.canvas)
      .append("svg") // ERROR RAISED ON THIS LINE
      .attr("width", canvasWidth)
      .attr("height", canvasHeight)
      .style("border", "1px solid black");
    console.log(svgCanvas);
    svgCanvas.selectAll("rect")
      .data(data).enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", 40)
      .attr("height", ((datapoint: number) => datapoint * scale))
      .attr("fill", "orange")
      .attr("x", (datapoint: number, iteration: number) => iteration * 45)
      .attr("y", ((datapoint: number) => canvasHeight - datapoint * scale));
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.canvas} />
    );
  }
}

export default BarChart;
```

This should have produced the bar chart shown in the tutorial but instead I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElementNS' of undefined` on the line with `.append('svg')`.

EDIT: console log screenshot at https://pasteboard.co/IwQ441d.png

Answer (score 1):

I was able to avoid this error by changing `d3.select(this.canvas)` to `d3.select(this.canvas.current)`.